# How can I make a StackLayout with ngFor loop into scrollable list?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

```
 <StackLayout width="100%" *ngFor="let item of (videos$ | async)">
     <CardView class="studentCard" margin="2" elevation="10" radius="1">
        <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="auto, auto, *">
            <Image [src]="item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0"></Image>
            <Label [text]="item.snippet.channelTitle" textWrap="true" row="2" colSpan="1" ></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.snippet.title" textWrap="true" row="2" col="1" colSpan="2" >></Label>
        </GridLayout>
     </CardView>
 </StackLayout>
```

I tried to wrap it in `ScrollView`, didn't work.

I couldn't make `(items$ | async)` work with `ListView` either, seems `ngFor` can't work with `ListView`, we need `ng-template` for `ListView`.

I tried the following but only the first item is rendering

```
<ScrollView>
  <ListView [items]="videos$ | async" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
       <GridLayout  class="list-group-item">
         <Image [src]="item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url"></Image>
         <Label [text]="item.snippet.channelTitle" ></Label>
         <Label [text]="item.snippet.title">></Label>
       </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wraping the entire code first with `StackLayout` then with `ScrollView` worked

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>

   <StackLayout width="100%" *ngFor="let item of (videos$ | async)">
       <CardView class="studentCard" margin="2" elevation="10" radius="1">
          <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="auto, auto, *">
              <Image [src]="item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0"></Image>
              <Label [text]="item.snippet.channelTitle" textWrap="true" row="2" colSpan="1" ></Label>
              <Label [text]="item.snippet.title" textWrap="true" row="2" col="1" colSpan="2" >></Label>
          </GridLayout>
       </CardView>
   </StackLayout>

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```